# Retrieving data from MDX request Mondrian

Tags: java, arrays, mdx, mondrian

I am trying to get all the data from an `MDX` request. For example, I want to `foreach` every row in the result. I have the following code:

```
String cnxURL =
    "Jdbc=jdbc:" +
    "postgresql://localhost/foodmart;" +
    "JdbcDrivers=org.postgresql.Driver;" +
    "JdbcUser=postgres;" +
    "JdbcPassword=postgres;" +
    "Catalog=file:../queries/FoodMart.xml;";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(cnxURL, null);

String query = "Select ...";
Query q = connection.parseQuery(query);
Result result = connection.execute(q);
```

I tried `result.getCell(new int[]{0,0})`, but I don't know how many rows and what dimension my result has. I also tried to use `PrintWriter` like:

```
File f = new File("output");
try {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
    result.print(pw);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
```

but only one query out of ten got printed.

What am i doing wrong here? How can get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a code sample here: [Presentation of data from Mondrian OLAP engine + Olap4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893993/presentation-of-data-from-mondrian-olap-engine-olap4j). And there is another one at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/olap4j/sample/SimpleQuerySample.java.html.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Code samples for the olap4j library](https://code.google.com/p/olap4j-demo/source/browse/trunk/src/org/devdonkey/olap4j/demo/QueryDemo.java).

Comment: thanks a lot! It made me near to the solution. But all of the examples use a `PrintWriter`, which doesn't help me access to separate cells with their values.